# How to make negative numbers not count when doing addition (C++)

Tags: c++

i tried making a program like this for schoolwork but it dosent work can somebody help me please, i dont really know where to go

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;
   cout<<"enter 3 numbers"<<endl;
   cin>>a;
   cin>>b;
   cin>>c;
   d = a + b + c
   if ( a <= 1 - = 0 )
    cout<<d<<endl;
   if ( b < 1 - = 0 )
   cout<<d<<endl;
   else ( c < 1 - = 0 )



   return 0;
```

Comment: If "it dosent work" fix it. Alternatively allow us to help by describing how exactly it does not work. What happens? What faild to happen? What output do you expect in contrast to what you get?

Comment: Obviously "doesnt work" does not refer to the fact that it is not possible to compile your code because of the missing `}` at the end, does it?

Comment: the program wont compile i added a ```}``` at the end

Comment: If the problem is compilation, then read and post the compiler errors. In full, verbatim, directly here and as text please. No pictures of text, please.

Comment: @Xeku there are MANY things that can be wrong with a program. We are volunteers and (as I sometimes lie to myself) our time is valuable. We're here answering questions because we WANT to help. But we need something from you beforehand. What EXACT error are you getting? Please see [ask] for more info on how to ask a good question. Asking a good question takes more time, but it has two benefits: 1. you're more likely to get the help you need since its easier on us, and 2. it might help you learn and understand the problem better while taking the time to form the question.

Comment: That's not how syntax for if/else works. To be honest I don't even know what you're trying to do in your if statements.

Comment: To make things short. Please delete the question to have time for improving it. Then read [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and [mre]. Then [edit] to add details, explanation and otherwise improve it. Then undelete it.

Comment: so im trying to make a program that ignores negative numbers 
and im getting this error : expected primary-expression before '=' token 
i added ; at  d = a + b + c

Comment: Please read my previous two comments, again or more thoroughly.

Comment: This code expresses a problem that I see sometimes with people that come from a mathematics background. The expression `d = a + b + c` does not establish an equality, it calculates a result that is copied into `d`. The value of `a+b+c` is calculated immediately, and that resulting number is assigned to `d`. Any future change to `a,` `b` or `c` are not reflected on `d`.

Comment: The true beauty of the [mcve] is it is hard to make one without discovering the problem in the process. If knowing what's wrong doesn't help you fix it or you have constructed a MRE and didn't sport the bug, then THAT is the time to ask a Question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Expressions in c++ end with a semi colon. You forgot the semicolon after `d = a + b + c`.

Comment: You should try to work out an algorithm with pen and paper first. Then write the code. Small hint: `d` could be zero. If `a` is non-negative add `a` to `d`. Repeat for `b` and `c`. And I'm a bit curious what this strange `if/else`-syntax is supposed to mean.

Comment: What do you want to happen if one of the terms is negative?

Comment: `int d = std::max(a,0) + std::max(b,0) + std::max(c,0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this:

```
int d = 0; // Initial value
if (a > 0)
{
    d = d + a;
}
if (b > 0)
{
    d = d + b;
}
if (c > 0)
{
    d = d + c;
}
```

In the above code, terms are only added to the `d` variable if they are positive.